# Slide Down Menu - How to allow only one path open at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, slidetoggle

Currently if I have a menu open and click on another one it opens the 2nd one and the 1st stays open. I can even have all open at the same time!

I'd like to change this behavior so that I never have more than one menu open at a time. (accounting for all levels/sub-menus)

Say I open "Home" and click on "Item 4". "Sub Item 1" and "Sub Item 2" appear. If I then click on "Contact" at the top the other menu that is open should close (ideally all levels should slide up one at a time) before "Contact" slides down.

I know the issue is the Javascript so I'm not gonna paste the HTML and CSS here to not take too much space.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfgoowx6/2/)

Thanks

```
$(function(){
    $('ul#menu li').on('click', function(){
         $(this).children('ul').delay(20).slideToggle(600);
    });
});

$('ul').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfgoowx6/5/)

JS code:

```
    $(function(){
        $('ul#menu li').on('click', function(){
            if($(this).children('.drop').size() > 0) {
                $("ul.drop").slideUp();
                $("ul.drop").find('ul').hide();
            } else {

            }

         $(this).children('ul').delay(20).slideToggle(600);
        });
    });

    $('ul').on('click', function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: Almost, the issue now is that if you go a few levels deep (Home>Item 4>Sub Item 1) and then move to another menu, when you click on Home again it opens all the way down to where you were... it really shouldn't.

Comment: Looks like it does! Thanks. What about not letting them overlap? Having the ones that are open slide up before the one you just clicked on slides down? is that possible?

Comment: I think, you can just do a `.hide()` instead of `.slideUp()`. That would reduce the overlap. BTW, if this answer worked for you, would you accept this? :)

Comment: I'm happy to accept it as you fixed the most important issue. No problem. ;) Unfortunately there's just no way I can lose slideUp. Is it to hard to fix this part or simply not doable?